# setText and findViewById not in OnCreate crashes App

Tags: java, android, xml, bluetooth, ibeacon

I'm trying to change a Text Label to output the current range value, so I create a variable **TextView rangeElement;** in the beginning of my MainActivity.

In my OnCreate Method I link it to the ID placed in my XML file with **rangeElement = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.range);**

That works perfectly fine. But I have another method, which is looking for bluetooth beacons and gives me the range I want to print. It's called **void onBeaconServiceConnect()** and starts when the beacon service is running and ready to accept your commands through the BeaconManager. That seems to happen before my View is loaded and so my App crashes as soon as the onBeaconServiceConnect is trying to acces the variable with **rangeElement.setText("Range: " + oneBeacon.getDistance());**

I am using *Android Beacon Library 2.8 API* - does someone know how I can prevent the app to crash when trying to change the text label?

PS: Here is my full code

```
public class BeaconActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements BeaconConsumer{

public static final String TAG = "BeaconsEverywhere";
// Beacon Manager Variable
private BeaconManager beaconManager;

TextView rangeElement;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_beacon);

    // Variablen für Elemente, die in der XML angepasst werden sollen
    rangeElement = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.range);

    // Instantiieren des Beacon Managers mit Factory Method
    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

    // Sag der Library wie die Signale decodiert werden sollen
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser()
            // 2015=beac
            .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));

    beaconManager.bind(this);
}

// Implementieren der BeaconConsumer Methode
@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    final org.altbeacon.beacon.Region region = new org.altbeacon.beacon.Region("myBeacons", Identifier.parse("73676723-7400-0000-ffff-0000ffff0005"), null, null);
    beaconManager.setMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didEnterRegion(org.altbeacon.beacon.Region region) {
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "did Enter Region");
                beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void didExitRegion(org.altbeacon.beacon.Region region) {
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "did Exit Region");
                beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, org.altbeacon.beacon.Region region) {

        }
    });

    beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        //Log out welche beacons in der Nähe sind
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, org.altbeacon.beacon.Region region) {
            for(Beacon oneBeacon : beacons) {
                Log.d(TAG, "distance: " + oneBeacon.getDistance() + "id: " + oneBeacon.getId1() + "/" + oneBeacon.getId2() + "/" + oneBeacon.getId3());
                //rangeElement.setText("Range: " + oneBeacon.getDistance());
            }
        }
    });

    try {
        beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    beaconManager.unbind(this);
}
```

PPS: I exportet the thread when the uncaught exeption happens in Line 72 of the RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler (com.android.internal.os):

```
main@20986, prio=5, in group 'main', status: 'RUNNING'
      at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Binder.java:-1)
      at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
      at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGatt$Stub$Proxy.registerClient(IBluetoothGatt.java:889)
      at android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner$BleScanCallbackWrapper.startRegisteration(BluetoothLeScanner.java:286)
      at android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner.startScan(BluetoothLeScanner.java:140)
      at android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner.startScan(BluetoothLeScanner.java:104)
      at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScannerForLollipop.startScan(CycledLeScannerForLollipop.java:187)
      at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScanner.scanLeDevice(CycledLeScanner.java:190)
      at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScanner.finishScanCycle(CycledLeScanner.java:266)
      at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScanner.scheduleScanCycleStop(CycledLeScanner.java:239)
      at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScanner$1.run(CycledLeScanner.java:235)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6873)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:-1)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

Signal Catcher@21301 daemon, prio=5, in group 'system', status: 'WAIT'
     Incompatible thread state: thread not suspended

ReferenceQueueDaemon@21302 daemon, prio=5, in group 'system', status: 'WAIT'
     blocks ReferenceQueueDaemon@21302
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.run(Daemons.java:149)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

FinalizerDaemon@21303 daemon, prio=5, in group 'system', status: 'WAIT'
     blocks FinalizerDaemon@21303
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:422)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:101)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:72)
      at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:189)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

FinalizerWatchdogDaemon@21304 daemon, prio=5, in group 'system', status: 'WAIT'
     blocks FinalizerWatchdogDaemon@21304
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.waitForObject(Daemons.java:255)
      at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run(Daemons.java:227)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Binder_1@21305, prio=5, in group 'main', status: 'RUNNING'
     Incompatible thread state: thread not suspended

HeapTrimmerDaemon@21306 daemon, prio=5, in group 'system', status: 'WAIT'
     blocks HeapTrimmerDaemon@21306
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Daemons$HeapTrimmerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:326)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

GCDaemon@21307 daemon, prio=5, in group 'system', status: 'WAIT'
     blocks GCDaemon@21307
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Daemons$GCDaemon.run(Daemons.java:359)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Binder_2@21308, prio=5, in group 'main', status: 'RUNNING'
     Incompatible thread state: thread not suspended

RenderThread@21189, prio=5, in group 'main', status: 'RUNNING'
     Incompatible thread state: thread not suspended

hwuiTask1@21265, prio=5, in group 'main', status: 'RUNNING'
     Incompatible thread state: thread not suspended

pool-2-thread-1@21274, prio=5, in group 'main', status: 'WAIT'
     blocks pool-2-thread-1@21274
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1220)
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

pool-2-thread-2@21279, prio=5, in group 'main', status: 'WAIT'
     blocks pool-2-thread-2@21279
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1220)
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

IntentService[BeaconIntentProcessor]@21291, prio=5, in group 'main', status: 'WAIT'
      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:72)
      at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
      at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)

pool-2-thread-3@21296, prio=5, in group 'main', status: 'RUNNING'
      at java.lang.IntegralToString.longToHexString(IntegralToString.java:508)
      at java.lang.Long.toHexString(Long.java:443)
      at java.util.UUID.toString(UUID.java:420)
      at org.altbeacon.beacon.Identifier.toString(Identifier.java:242)
      at org.altbeacon.beacon.Beacon.toStringBuilder(Beacon.java:502)
      at org.altbeacon.beacon.Beacon.hashCode(Beacon.java:450)
      at java.util.Collections.secondaryHash(Collections.java:3405)
      at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:300)
      at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.RangeState.addBeacon(RangeState.java:50)
      at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.BeaconService.processBeaconFromScan(BeaconService.java:422)
      at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.BeaconService.access$500(BeaconService.java:76)
      at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.BeaconService$ScanProcessor.doInBackground(BeaconService.java:467)
      at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.BeaconService$ScanProcessor.doInBackground(BeaconService.java:442)
      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

pool-2-thread-4@21314, prio=5, in group 'main', status: 'MONITOR'
     waiting for pool-2-thread-3@21296 to release lock on <0x5358> (a java.util.HashMap)
      at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.BeaconService.processBeaconFromScan(BeaconService.java:414)
      at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.BeaconService.access$500(BeaconService.java:76)
      at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.BeaconService$ScanProcessor.doInBackground(BeaconService.java:467)
      at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.BeaconService$ScanProcessor.doInBackground(BeaconService.java:442)
      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Binder_3@21319, prio=5, in group 'main', status: 'RUNNING'
     Incompatible thread state: thread not suspended
```

The appended message has the following values:
**[F,A,T,A,L, ,E,X,C,E,P,T,I,O,N,:, ,I,n,t,e,n,t,S,e,r,v,i,c,e,[,B,e,a,c,o,n,I,n,t,e,n,t,P,r,o,c,e,s,s,o,r,],
,**

Comment: Please, post some relevant code

Comment: I updated the question with the code

Comment: are you sure rangeElement is not null in onCreate()? Put some logs into onCreate and into a function where rangeElement is null to see which is called first. I assume that action begins only after calling beaconManager.bind(this); and by this moment your textView should be found

Comment: I put a Log into OnCreate after where I declare my rangeElement and it is not null: 05-30 18:33:09.349  10747-10747/de.project.beacontut01 D/BeaconsEverywhere﹕ android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{2a3adc6c V.ED.... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f090054 app:id/range}"

Comment: I've created test project using your code, and created my own xml layout with LinearView and TextView. onCreate function was called first, then onBeaconServiceConnect. rangeElement was not null. I wasnt able to get didRangeBeaconsInRegion() callback though.. I have no idea when its called. Is it possible that callback is called after rangeElement is being destroyed?

Comment: did you resolve your problem?

Comment: I did set up a breakpoint at **beaconManager.unbind(this);** and the app crashed before it was reached :(

Comment: If I just use Log.d(TAG, "distance: " + oneBeacon.getDistance()) the App never crashes and I see the values in the console popping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onBeaconServiceConnect()` callback is made only in response to the `beaconManager.bind(this);` call, which is in `onCreate()`.  Based on the code shown, I do not think it is possible for `onBeaconServiceConnect()` to be called before the `onCreate` method, so the `rangeElement = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.range);` line must have been executed.

One explanation is that `findViewById(R.id.range);` is returning null.  Are you certain that this element identifier is defined in the R.layout.activity_beacon?  If you believe it is, I would add a debug line to `onCreate`, or set a breakpoint there to verify the call is returning a non-null value.

**EDIT:** Another possibility is that the exception is caused by trying to update the UI on a non-UI thread.  Beacon callbacks are typucally not on the UI thread.  Try wrapping your UI updates like this:

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            rangeElement.setText("Range: " + oneBeacon.getDistance()); 
        }
    });
```

Comment: I checked that there is actually a value for Range / Distance. It is, as you can see here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/07zjyhrg9yimw23/01.jpg?dl=0
But there is also an uncaught handler as seen here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/paqt619boo10eb0/02.jpg?dl=0
and here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tw357rp0o81yb04/03.jpg?dl=0

Comment: I also tried another value, like .getId1() which also gets the App crashed.

Comment: Indeed you are right. :) I added your code and also I had to make oneBeacon final with the following line of code: **for(final Beacon oneBeacon : beacons) {**
After this, it does not crash anymore, thank you!
Do you have a good source I can read more about UI threads?

Comment: Glad that fixed it.  The stack trace was a bit unusual for that to be the problem. You can read more here: https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Comment: For anyone interested, I found a nice two part video series which explains why I have to put this into a new thread and create a runnable:
https://youtu.be/2P2mXutRdkE

Answer (score 0):

Just doing this you can check if rangeElement is already initialized or not, so app is not going to crash:

```
if(rangeElement != null){
    rangeElement.setText("Range: " + oneBeacon.getDistance());
}
```

Comment: I used your code for checking if it is not null. But still the app is crashing as soon as I use the line **rangeElement.setText("Range: " + oneBeacon.getDistance());** in it.

Adding an else line where it prints "Element is NULL", is also never the case.

I added a debug message right after this line. It is never reached, because the app crashes when reaching the setText alread. On the screen I can just see the label chaning to "Range: " and then there is no value behind it. Then it crashes